# How to properly use jsPDF library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jspdf

I want to convert some of my divs into PDF and I've tried jsPDF library but with no success. It seems I can't understand what I need to import to make the library work. I've been through the examples and I still can't figure it out. I've tried the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

After jQuery and:

```
$("#html2pdf").on('click', function(){
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.fromHTML($('body').get(0), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170
    });
    console.log(doc);
});
```

for testing purposes but I receive:

```
"Cannot read property '#smdadminbar' of undefined"
```

where `#smdadminbar` is the first div from the body.

Comment: the one which worked for me https://github.com/devrajatverma/jsPdfExample

Comment: Note for all who get here trying to figure out `fromHTML` or why it isn't documented in the jsPDF docs: "_We are closing this issue, because we will not support any longer fromHTML and addHTML._" ([from issue#516](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/516#issuecomment-419228701))

Answer (score 150, accepted):

you can use pdf from html as follows,

#### Step 1: Add the following script to the header

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

[or download locally](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

#### Step 2: Add HTML script to execute jsPDF code

Customize this to pass the identifier or just change #content to be the identifier you need.

```
 <script>
    function demoFromHTML() {
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
        // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
        // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
        source = $('#content')[0];

        // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
        // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
        // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
        // (class, of compound) at this time.
        specialElementHandlers = {
            // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
            '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
                // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
                return true
            }
        };
        margins = {
            top: 80,
            bottom: 60,
            left: 40,
            width: 522
        };
        // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
        // 'inches' in this case
        pdf.fromHTML(
            source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
            margins.left, // x coord
            margins.top, { // y coord
                'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            },

            function (dispose) {
                // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
                //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
                pdf.save('Test.pdf');
            }, margins
        );
    }
</script>
```

#### Step 3: Add your body content

```
<a href="javascript:demoFromHTML()" class="button">Run Code</a>
<div id="content">
    <h1>  
        We support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style.
    </h1>
</div>
```

#### [Refer to the original tutorial](http://parall.ax/products/jspdf)

#### [See a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzZ7n/4861/)

Comment: Thanks for posting this, but I tried the exact code above (locally) and it generates a blank pdf document.  It doesn't work at all with jquery 1.11.0 so i used the same jquery version as used on https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/examples/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js

Comment: Tried your code @Well Wisher , its giving me the following error , for the library file itdself -- Cannot read property 'length' of undefined jspdf.plugin.from_html.js:500

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h59sG/ and the libraries which i have used are <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script>
   
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>

Comment: Your answer is so valuable. See it @Wellwisher.. The same answer posted two times here itself. Please edit. I don't want someone drop your credit.

Comment: I have been able to convert pages to PDF fine with this, but I am stumped on how to preserve the styling, or at least not have the output look terrible.

I have not been able to find any info or documentation on this.

Please have a look at how this pdf outputs:
http://devious.runningh20.com/php-runs/dophin/

You can view-source to see the code.

Comment: The July 24 2014 code produces a blank page.  I've edited this to fit the working fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/xzz7n/1/  
Hopefully it will be peer reviewed soon. Look for an edit date of Oct 28 2015 to know if it is working code.

Comment: Yes this is really good,,, But the output of JSPdf is overlapping with another elements of my table elements , How Can i solve it?.... I have changed the size of the fonts and made it as landscape mode , I tried most of the modifications , But nothing is working

Comment: @SudhirBelagali can you please create a fiddle.?

Comment: It's really odd that the latest release of jspdf will not work, but if you specifically get the 1.0.272 release and use the above code, it will work. Cannot tell you how frustrating getting blank pages, JS errors about "1 not being defined", etc.

Comment: I was only able to get this example to work by using the CloudFlare CDNs: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.debug.js"></script> or <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.min.js"></script> But I agree, documentation, and general variations in code source, contribute to the difficulty of using this plugin. Even these CDNs (which the JSfiddle use) vary from the "download locally" link @Well wisher references above.

Comment: @Scott i the they removed the link

Comment: @Well wisher - that's a risk. Which is why I copied and pasted it's contents into a locally-hosted JS file. Problem solved!

Comment: I have this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null
    at Object.jsPDFAPI.sHashCode

Comment: Including this script is also very important                                        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I also want to know how to embed a live updating pdf preview like in that jspdf website !

Comment: how do I make this to print my CSS styles?

Comment: FYI. The fiddle provided in this answer uses `.fromHTML` which was deprecated in November 2018.

Comment: this worked for me after also adding a reference to the jQuery library.

Comment: thanks, I was unable to find what were the inputs of the fromHTML function in nowhere else haha

Answer (score 20):

You only need this link [jspdf.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js)

It has everything in it.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was driving me nuts! Using the debug version of jspdf worked, where the other versions in any configuration did not. Maybe minification is breaking it somehow? or I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: This really helped me. I was using the original jspdf.js file and it wasn't working. Using jspdf.debug.js did the job.

Comment: Interesting why the production version is not working... I included all the plugins in html page and yet, only this debug version helped.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but I get error `Error in function FileSaver@http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.debug.js:5875:18: get_URL(...).createObjectURL is not a function`, same thing if I use the bower version. Any clue?

Comment: Check the latest version on GitHub and change the URL above accordingly. Latest is 1.3.5.

Comment: Instead of using a specific version for the library, you can just include the latest stable version by just adding; `<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @AhmetGokdayi `https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.min.js` returns `Cannot find "/dist/jspdf.min.js" in jspdf@2.2.0`

Comment: @omegastripes Looks like they updated the source; `https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.umd.min.js`

Answer (score 14):

According to the latest version (1.5.3) there is no `fromHTML()` method anymore.
Instead you should utilize jsPDF HTML plugin, see: https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-html.html#~html

You also need to add html2canvas library in order for it to work properly: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas

**JS** (from API docs):

```
var doc = new jsPDF();   

doc.html(document.body, {
   callback: function (doc) {
     doc.save();
   }
});
```

You can provide HTML string instead of reference to the DOM element as well.

Comment: Doesnt seem to work anymore either - jQuery.Deferred exception: doc.html is not a function TypeError: doc.html is not a function

Comment: Did you find a solution? fromHTML is working in the latest download. But, svg elements are not rendered in the downloaded PDF.

Comment: @mythicalcoder I actually ended up writing my own class that will take the DOM tree and will construct the actual PDF using internal jsPDF APIs. That way it is actually a text and not a rasterized screenshot of your page.

Comment: Seems much better. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 12):

This is finally what did it for me (and triggers a disposition):

```js
function onClick() {
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
  pdf.canvas.height = 72 * 11;
  pdf.canvas.width = 72 * 8.5;

  pdf.fromHTML(document.body);

  pdf.save('test.pdf');
};

var element = document.getElementById("clickbind");
element.addEventListener("click", onClick);
```

```html
<h1>Dsdas</h1>

<a id="clickbind" href="#">Click</a>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

> And for those of the KnockoutJS inclination, a little binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.generatePDF = {
    init: function(element) {

        function onClick() {
            var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
            pdf.canvas.height = 72 * 11;
            pdf.canvas.width = 72 * 8.5;

            pdf.fromHTML(document.body);

            pdf.save('test.pdf');                    
        };

        element.addEventListener("click", onClick);
    }
};
```

Comment: Is there more to this snippet? When I try to run this I get an error that indicates 'pdf.canvas' is undefined.

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'height' of undefined"

Comment: Not sure what you mean? The snippet executes using the same code. So perhaps something is off in your implementation. Can you console.log(pdf) and share the output.

Comment: It must have been a caching issue or something, when I attempted it just now with the console.log() in there, the code executed correctly. I'm still getting the blank page issue, but that's a different story. Thanks.

Comment: also i have error **"Cannot read property 'addEventListener'"**

Comment: I am loving this jsPDF() library. BTW if anyone else finds this useful I just figured out the syntax for attaching a callback to run after the PDF has been generated: `pdf.save("myfile.pdf", function(){ alert("pdf generation/save finished!"); });`

Answer (score 4):

how about in vuejs how is it applicable?

```js
function onClick() {
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
  pdf.canvas.height = 72 * 11;
  pdf.canvas.width = 72 * 8.5;

  pdf.fromHTML(document.body);

  pdf.save('test.pdf');
};

var element = document.getElementById("clickbind");
element.addEventListener("click", onClick);
```

```html
<h1>Dsdas</h1>

<a id="clickbind" href="#">Click</a>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the vuejs example of using jdpsf

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't you also be using the jspdf.plugin.from_html.js library? Besides the main library (jspdf.js), you must use other libraries for "special operations" (like jspdf.plugin.addimage.js for using images). Check https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF.

Comment: The jspdf.source.js seems to include all of the other libraries.

Answer (score 3):

first, you have to create a handler.

```
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function(element, renderer){
        return true;
    }
};
```

then write this code in click event:

```
doc.fromHTML($('body').get(0), 15, 15, {
    'width': 170, 
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });

var pdfOutput = doc.output();
            console.log(">>>"+pdfOutput );
```

assuming you've already declared doc variable.
And Then you have save this pdf file using File-Plugin.