# Jquery to Save as PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

I have tried the method as given by WellWisher in the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858954/how-to-properly-use-jspdf-library), but I am getting error as `"Object doesn't support this property or method"` in the file `jspdf.js` line 357 which is

```
"var fontKey = 'F' + (Object.keys(fonts).length + 1).toString(10)"
```

Can someone please help.

Regards,
Preetish

Comment: Did you add all REQUIRED *.js?

Comment: yes added all the js. as given in the example. I am using IE 8. Not sure what is missing.