# I am generating a pdf file using jspdf library and I am getting the error "jspdf is not defined"

Tags: javascript, php, joomla, jspdf

[image]I am just trying to create a pdf file and I am getting the error "jspdf is not defined"

Here is my code

```
<?php

        $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
        $doc->addScript(JUri::base() .'js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js',true);
        $doc->addScript(JUri::base() .'js/jspdf.debug.js',true);
        $doc->addScript(JUri::base() .'js/basic.js',true);
        $doc->addScript(JUri::base() .'js/png.js',true);
        $doc->addScript(JUri::base() .'js/png_support.js',true);
        $doc->addScript(JUri::base() .'js/zlib.js',true);
        $doc->addScript(JUri::base() .'js/FileSaver.js',true);
        $doc->addScript(JUri::base() .'js/tableExport.js',true);
        $doc->addScript(JUri::base() .'js/jquery.base64.js',true);
        $doc->addScript(JUri::base() .'js/html2canvas.js',true);
        $doc->addScript(JUri::base() .'js/standard_fonts_metrics.js',true);
        $doc->addScript(JUri::base() .'js/split_text_to_size.js',true);
        $doc->addScript(JUri::base() .'js/from_html.js',true);
    $script = "function loadtable(){
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world.');
    doc.save('Test.pdf');}";
    $doc->addScriptDeclaration($script);
    echo "<button id='buttonMU' class='gen_btn' onclick='loadtable()'>Load Pdf</button>";
    ?>
```

But I do have the javscript included in my php code.
Please advise.

Comment: When you look at the source code you receive in your browser, do you see all the script declarations? In the `Network` tab of your debugger, do you see any 404 errors?

Comment: Yes, I do see all the script declarations.No,I don't see any 404 errors.

Comment: @blexUpdated the code. I missed to copy it from the actual  code.

Comment: Where is your inclusion of  jspdf.min.js? I checked the library on github, and it has two files:  jspdf.debug.js, and jspdf.min.js. You might be missing a dependency.

Comment: @MartynShutt Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/26784344/768294

Comment: @Learner2011. Ah, I see. Does your function appear in the source as well as the script declarations?

Comment: @Martyn ShuttI do see them in the source.

Answer (score 0):

Check the source code of your output page. You're probably calling your javascript function before the DOM has finished loading.

Try ensuring your code runs after the page has loaded;

```
object.onload=function(){myScript};

$script = "window.onload = function(){
    function loadtable(){
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world.');
    doc.save('Test.pdf');
}";
```

Comment: No, he's not calling it too early, since it is triggered by a button's `onclick` event listener. In fact, waiting for the document to be loaded will result in the `loadtable` function being undefined at DOM parsing time.

Comment: @blex ah, fair enough. Just wanted to rule it out. It's a common issue I've come across in Joomla.

Comment: @MartynShuttSeems to me like a Joomla issue.I was able to generate the pdf file  in a html page but in a php page it is failing.

Comment: @Learner2011 Joomla can be very particular, and hard to debug sometimes.