# Generating PDF from array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, pdf, pdf-generation

How to generate pdf from 2d array, as mentioned below, in JavaScript
Sample Array
var datasets=[[1.0,199.6],[2.0,205.05],[3.0,283.6],[4.0,220.15],[5.0,313.05]];

Comment: Use jsPDF.

Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858954/how-to-properly-use-jspdf-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a client side solution](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) for generating PDF files using JavaScript only.

**Code:**

```
var data = [[1.0,199.6],[2.0,205.05],[3.0,283.6],[4.0,220.15],[5.0,313.05]];
var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.setFontSize(40);
doc.text(35, 25, data.map(function(e){ return e.join("\t"); }).join("\n"));
```