# HTML+Images to PDF using jsPDF

Tags: jquery, html, image, pdf, jspdf

I have HTML dashboard,which contain HTML+CSS+images+SVG code. Is it possible to convert this code to PDF? 
I want to use `addHTML` method.
If yes,then can any one provide me the working example.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly use jsPDF library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858954/how-to-properly-use-jspdf-library)

Comment: The solution in this link is not giving me proper output.

Comment: Then mention in your question what you're trying, what you have, what you're getting etc. Be as specific as you can.

Comment: @hjpotter92: please check now