# download pdf format not proper

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please check the link
https://jsfiddle.net/dhaileytaha/1wmk9gsq/14/

```
<script>
 /*Download option*/
var doc = new jsPDF();
    var specialElementHandlers = { 
 '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
    };
          doc.fromHTML($('#example').html(), 55, 55, {
        'width': 170,
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });


document.getElementById("cmd").onclick = function () {

    var pass1= "cool" ;

password=prompt('Please enter your password to Print this page!',' ');

if (password==pass1)
{ 
       doc.save('target-file.pdf');
   } else {
       window.alert('Sorry! You are not Authorsised');   
   }
 }

</script>
```

it is a datatable. I am able to print it in proper format but not able to download in the same FORMAT as the datatable is.
Please help
I want the same format as of the DATATABLE in pdf form.

Comment: Look at this post: a nice working example attached. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858954/how-to-properly-use-jspdf-library

Answer (score 0):

Your jspdf resource you are using is an old one probably and does not work properly.

Another thing you should do, is wrap the content with a div tag.

I tried out your fiddle example with the following version and it works.
http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.debug.js

Comment: can u share your fiddle?