# getting error Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, console, jspdf

Hi i followed following link but still getting error Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined
[How to properly use jsPDF library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858954/how-to-properly-use-jspdf-library) I have copied all data and run on my xampp but still getting same error in console. Could anyone please help me to solve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Make sure you're adding lib JS before `demoFromHTML()` function is called.

Comment: "jsPDF is not defined" means that, er, jsPDF isn't defined, so you have a script loading problem.

Comment: You should download the js file from that link and add it with script tag to your project

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
I've tried whatever you said but it's not effect on my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Download jspdf.min.js file and add that in your program, and locate that path as below,

```
 <script src="this file path/jspdf.min.js">
 </script> <script src="this file path/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script> (<---If needed)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
I've tried whatever you said but it's not effect on my problem.

Comment: Can you please show me your code ? So that i can find out where the problem is exactly on .

Comment: Hi Becky
Thanks for your reply.

first i've added following js but it was not working 
(http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.debug.js)

Now i've tried with following js now its working properly 
(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.debug.js)

Thank you

Comment: Sounds Good . Super :)