# Print PDF from html page from Inbox (mail)

Tags: javascript, html, email, pdf, jspdf

I was following below link and it's extremely helpful. I wanted to know how we can make HTML page print as PDF from inbox of gmail or any other mailing system.
Is it possible to do so !!
Link : http://jsfiddle.net/xzZ7n/4861/

[How to properly use jsPDF library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858954/how-to-properly-use-jspdf-library)

```
    function demoFromHTML() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
    // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
    source = $('#content')[0];

    // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
    // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
    // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
    // (class, of compound) at this time.
    specialElementHandlers = {
        // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
        '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
            // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
            return true
        }
    };
    margins = {
        top: 80,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 40,
        width: 522
    };
    // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
    // 'inches' in this case
    pdf.fromHTML(
        source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
        margins.left, // x coord
        margins.top, { // y coord
            'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        },

        function (dispose) {
            // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
            //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
            pdf.save('Test.pdf');
        }, margins
    );
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to print the actual email? Or the download option will download a PDF or some file.

Comment: Print actual email

Comment: Can you give me an example why you'd want to do that? The email clients already implemented that for you.

Comment: @MosesDavidowitz yes...we have some HTML formated Mail in inbox like invoice so we want user to allow to print them if they want.