# Html Table into PDF using jsPDF plugin

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

Here is Html Table Code:

```
<table id="tab_customers" class="table table-bordered table-striped hidden">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Total Income</th>
            <th>Total Expenses</th>
            <th>Total Profit</th>
            <th>Total Loss</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      <tr>
         <td><?php if(!empty($month_name)) { echo $month_name; } else { echo '-';}?></td>
         <td><?php if(!empty($total_income)) { echo $total_income; } else { echo '0';}?></td>
         <td><?php if(!empty($total_expenses)) { echo $total_expenses; } else { echo '0';}?></td>
         <td><?php if(!empty($total_profit)) { echo $total_profit; } else { echo '0';}?></td>
         <td><?php if(!empty($total_loss)) { echo $total_loss; } else { echo '0';}?></td>

      </tr>
   </tbody>
```

Script Code:

```
<script>
function demoFromHTML() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    source = $('#tab_customers')[0];
    specialElementHandlers = {
        '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
            return true
        }
    };
    margins = {
        top: 80,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 70,
        width: 800
    };
    pdf.fromHTML(
        source,
        margins.left,
        margins.top, {
            'width': margins.width,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        },

        function (dispose) {
            pdf.save('Test.pdf');
        }, margins);
}
```

This plugin is working fine but the issue is the html table design to PDF is not correct attach is the resulted picture of PDF.
[image]

I am new to use this plugin Please guide me about how to set table design in PDF.

Thanks to all for any help

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xzZ7n/4861/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858954/how-to-properly-use-jspdf-library