# JsPDF problems with print add HTML

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I'm having trouble using JSPdf's `addHTML`, technically everything is working, but it does not print all the content that is in my div that I set, it only prints what I can see on the screen. Has anyone ever experienced this?

```
let doc = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4')
        let source = document.getElementById('draft')

        let options = {
            format: 'PNG',
            pagesplit: false
        }

        doc.addHTML(source, 0, 0, options, function(){
          doc.output('dataurlnewwindow')
        })
```

Comment: isn't the default (that makes sense) behavior?

Comment: it prints what you draw on `canvas` (in other words, what you see on screen)

Comment: @taha 
But is there any way I can print everything in my div? Even what I do not see?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858954/how-to-properly-use-jspdf-library might be helpful