# Generate pdf with jspdf and Vue.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, vuejs2, jspdf

I am new with Vue.js, and I am trying to generate a PDF, but I have no idea how to do it.

This is what I have:

```
import * as jsPDF  from "jspdf"

export default {

  props: ['id'],


  methods: {
    pdf () {
      const doc = new jsPDF()
    }
  }

}
```

Error:

> Property or method "pdf" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Answer (score 37, accepted):

First import the PDF library as:

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf'
```

Then simply instantiate the object and give it the contents:

```
methods: {
  createPDF () {
    let pdfName = 'test'; 
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text("Hello World", 10, 10);
    doc.save(pdfName + '.pdf');
  }
}
```

Make sure to read the [documentation](http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/) for more

Comment: I'm seeing  "ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined" but when i do `new jspdf.jsPDF()` it works?

Comment: Well, considering this was answered 3 years ago, something must have been updated. make sure the methods file has access to the file importer

Comment: How to use this if we put external web url?

Comment: @user7411584 I think you need to download the file first

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you guide me on this? If i put any web URL to download innerHTML first?

Comment: @user7411584 check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126825/1640606

Answer (score 31):

Download html page content, One can follow as:

1. Specify the ref to the element, whose content you want to download as pdf

   ```
   <div ref="content">
      ....
      ..
   </div>
   ```
2. Create a button download like

   ```
   <button @click="download">Download PDF</button>
   ```
3. Make sure to add & import jsPDF library into vue-component

   ```
   import jsPDF from 'jspdf' 
   import html2canvas from "html2canvas"
   ```
4. Specify the method into the VUE component like

   ```
   methods: {
    download() {
     const doc = new jsPDF();
     const contentHtml = this.$refs.content.innerHTML;
     doc.fromHTML(contentHtml, 15, 15, {
       width: 170
     });
     doc.save("sample.pdf");
    },

    downloadWithCSS() {
      const doc = new jsPDF();
      /** WITH CSS */
      var canvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');
       html2canvas(this.$refs.content, { canvas: canvasElement 
         }).then(function (canvas) {
       const img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.8);
       doc.addImage(img,'JPEG',20,20);
       doc.save("sample.pdf");
      });
    },
   }
   ```

   See the demo @[Download PDF via VUEJS](https://codesandbox.io/s/738o84vxnq).

Comment: Do you know how to make the external css applied as well for the contentHtml ?

Comment: @Exceptionhandler, I have updated the demo link for external css as well . check  https://codesandbox.io/s/738o84vxnq

Comment: @techyaura the "Download with CSS" button throws `5ms html2canvas: DOMException: "The operation is insecure.". interesting though !

Comment: Running the browser without CORS solves it for the purpose of this test.

Comment: The link you send for the demo is not working https://codesandbox.io/s/738o84vxnq

Comment: FYI, jsPDF no longer uses "fromHTML'. You'll need to use the 'html' function now. See more at http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-html.html

Comment: download with css is not working for me. I am getting a blank pdf

Comment: While any web URL as an input to convert this page to pdf ? How can i use this for web URL?

Answer (score 4):

Download html page content, One can follow as:

```
Specify the ref to the element, whose content you want to download as pdf

<div ref="content">
   ....
   ..
</div>
```

Create a button download like

```
<button @click="downloadWithCSS">Download PDF</button>
```

Make sure to add & import jsPDF library into vue-component

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf' 
import domtoimage from "dom-to-image";


Specify the method into the VUE component like

methods: {
 downloadWithCSS() {

   /** WITH CSS */
    domtoimage
    .toPng(this.$refs.content)
    .then(function(dataUrl) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = dataUrl;
      const doc = new jsPDF({
        orientation: "portrait",
        // unit: "pt",
        format: [900, 1400]
      });
      doc.addImage(img, "JPEG", 20, 20);
      const date = new Date();
      const filename =
        "timechart_" +
        date.getFullYear() +
        ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
        ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) +
        ("0" + date.getHours()).slice(-2) +
        ("0" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) +
        ("0" + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2) +
        ".pdf";
      doc.save(filename);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("oops, something went wrong!", error);
    });
 },
}
```

Comment: While any web URL as an input to convert this page to pdf ? How can i use this for web URL?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, especially with generating proper size and resolution.

To keep it brief, below is a link to the post:

[Using jsPDF, html2Canvas, and Vue to generate PDF's](https://dev.to/jringeisen/using-jspdf-html2canvas-and-vue-to-generate-pdfs-1f8l)

I modified for my use:

```
downloadItem() {
        const invoiceName = this.currentInvoice.invoiceId,
              content = this.$refs.invoiceContent;

        const doc = new jsPDF({
            orientation: "landscape",
            unit: "px",
            format: "a4",
            hotfixes: ["px_scaling"],
        });

        html2canvas(content, {
            width: doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth(),
            height: doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight(),
        }).then((canvas) => {
            const img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

            doc.addImage(
                img,
                "PNG",
                140,
                10,
                doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth(),
                doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight()
            );

            doc.save("invoice-" + invoiceName + ".pdf");
        });
    },
```

Link to the jsPDF Documentation below:

[jsPDF Documentation](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/)