# Text Field value not displaying in the download pdf when clicking the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jspdf

I'm a newbie. I can finally save my document as a pdf but the problem is the text in the textfield that i input was not display in the pdf file that i download. Here is my code.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <title>How To Download a DIV in a HTML Page as PDF File Using JavaScript</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Content Area -->
    <div id="print">

        <h3>Welcome To Veewom</h3>
        <p>This is a Sample Pararaph</p>
        <input type="text" id="try1" placeholder="Enter Name Here">



    </div>

    <div id="print-btn"></div>
    <button id="submit">Download PDF File</button>

</body>

</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#print-btn': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

$('#submit').click(function () {
    var fieldId = "field100";
    var chars = $('#try1').val();
    var chars2 = $('#try2').val();
    var chars3 = $('#try3').val();
    var d3 = $('[name=' + fieldId + ']:enabled').val();

    diff1 = "";
    if (d3) {
        diff = d3;
    }


    $('#veewom').html('<b>'+"One"+":"+'</b>'+ chars+
                '<b>'+"Two"+":"+'</b>'+chars2+
                '<b>'+"Three"+":"+'</b>'+chars3
                );

    var source = $('#print').html();
    doc.fromHTML(source, 15, 15, {
      'width': 170,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
  });
     doc.save('pdf-version.pdf');    
   });
```

This is the screenshot of the download pdf. I want to display the text that i input in this pdf file. but the problem is its only give me that content

[image: Save.pdf]

Comment: `var chars=$('try1').val();` to `var chars=$('#try1').val();`

Comment: i already try that but the problem is it is not download anymore the pdf

Comment: Check the other errors in the developer console. If you are thinking of adding a `#` cause error in downloading then you should read [JQUERY](https://www.w3schools.com/Jquery/default.asp)

Comment: It is now downloading i mean the pdf but still the text that i input still not displaying in the pdf

Comment: check it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858954/how-to-properly-use-jspdf-library) or [live test](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/)

Comment: it is now saving pdf but still the text that i input in the textfield is not displaying in the save pdf

Comment: post your updated code for that input field.

Comment: i already update it sir thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY THIS CODE

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="try1" placeholder="Enter Name Here">
<div id="print">
    <h3>Welcome To Veewom</h3>
    <p>This is a Sample Pararaph</p>
    <p id="veewom"></p>
</div>
```

Try this js code

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
  var fieldId = "field100";
  var chars = $('#try1').val();
  $('#veewom').html(chars);
  var d3 = $('[name=' + fieldId + ']:enabled').val();

  diff1 = "";
  if (d3) {
    diff = d3;
  }

  var source = $('#print').html();
  doc.fromHTML(source, 15, 15, {
    'width': 170,
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
  });
  doc.save('pdf-version.pdf');
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir now i finally see the input that i type in the textbox sir. Really Thank youuu :)

Comment: But sir why is it that the <p> div not appear in the save pdf. Thank you for your help. really appreciate it.

Comment: Cause you are replacing the content of `print` section with you input text

Comment: Thank you sir. But is it possible to display both paragraph and the text that i input sir ? really thank you sir

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. Really Thank you. You been a great help sir. Really Thank you :)

Comment: Sir can i ask? How can i add tab and spaces when saving in pdf file?

Comment: I updated my code sir i want to add new line and tab spaces when saving in pdf. Please help sir. Thank you