# how to get the height of a text in jsPDF

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

I am trying to print a variable that contains HTML. My problem is that the html is dinamic... for example...

```
// the number of <p> is dinamic... this value comes from a text editor.. 
//so the number of <p> can change...

   var text: "<div><p>Line 1</p><p> Line 2</p></div>"
```

So if in the bottom of this text i want to add something... i need to know the last position it typed or the height of this block...

there is any method to know what is the total height of this block? or .... what is the last coordinate typed?... or the number of lines...?

I am printing this variable like this...

```
var text = "<div><p>Line 1</p><p>Line 2</p></div>" 
doc.fromHTML(text,38,10).
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858954/how-to-properly-use-jspdf-library, there is a callback that gives you this information, see "Step 2".

Comment: thanks a lot! all solved! @JakeHolzinger