# html2pdf: How To Hide <div> From PDF?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, jspdf

I'm using `html2pdf`

I can Generate PDF of my Invoice, but i don't want a `<div class="div-dont-want-to-display">` to display on my PDF, how can i do that ?

My `Vue.js Component`:

```html
    <template>
      <div class="invoice p-3 mb-3" id="mydiv">

      <div class="div-dont-want-to-display">

      <!-- AND MANY MORE DIV'S -->

      <!--BUTTON TO DOWNLOAD PDF-->
        <a href @click.prevent="createPDF"class="btn btn-primary float-right">
          <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Generate PDF </a>
      </div>
    </template>
```

Method for `createPDF()`:

```js
import html2pdf from 'html2pdf.js'

export default {

  methods: {
    createPDF() {
      var element = document.getElementById('mydiv');

      var opt = {
        margin: 0,
        filename: 'myfile.pdf',
        image: {type: 'jpeg',quality: 0.98},
        html2canvas: {scale: 2},
        jsPDF: {
          unit: 'mm',
          format: [280, 350],
          orientation: 'portrait'
        }
      };

      html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save();
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: You want to generate the PDF from what?

Comment: @CodyG. Of course, I clearly mentioned it. I WANT TO DOWNLOAD `<div class="invoice">` as a PDF.

Comment: @LucasOliveira I am generation PDF with HELLO WORLD written in it. but i don't know how to download PDF with `<div class="invoice">`

Comment: @CodyG. Did this, getting nothing no error, no response, nothing....

Comment: i think i should go with html2pdf ....

Comment: Did this: `var ele = document.getElementById('mydiv')` now getting this error: `Cannot read property '1' of undefined`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the library [html2pdf](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf) that uses jsPDF and html2canvas.

The lib creates an PDF from a image of the div that you pass as an argument.

The code to call the lib after importing is as follows:

```js
var element = document.getElementById('content');
html2pdf(element);
```

```html
<div id="content">
  Test
</div>
```

You can pass some options too, more details on the github of the lib.

You can hide some elements using the following tag:

```
<div id="element-to-hide" data-html2canvas-ignore="true"></div>
```

Comment: @LucaOliveira i can download PDF, but there is a footer which i want to hide in PDF how can i do that ?

Comment: @SaifZakir Edited the answer try that!

Comment: @LucasReis thank you!! was looking for this all over!

Comment: @LucasReis Thanks! I imagined it would be simple but couldn't find this anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `id` to your div as follows :

```
  <div id="toprint" class="invoice" >
    ....
```

and in the method get the content of that div :

```
   let pdfName = 'test'; 
   var doc = new jsPDF();
   let content=document.getElementById("toprint").outerHTML
    doc.text(content, 10, 10);
    doc.save(pdfName + '.pdf');
```

or by using the default printing functionality in browser:

```
createPDF() {
  let content = document.getElementById("toprint").outerHTML;
  /******************** */
  let yourDOCTYPE = "<!DOCTYPE html...";
  let printPreview = window.open("", "print_preview");
  let printDocument = printPreview.document;
  printDocument.open();
  let head =
    "<head>" +
    "<title>" +
    this.title +
    "</title>" +
    +
    "</head>";

  printDocument.write(
    yourDOCTYPE +
    "<html>" +
    head +
    "<body>"
    content +
    "</body>" +
    "</html>"
  );
  printPreview.print();
  printPreview.close();
}
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this in my downloaded PDF: `<div id="toprint" class="invoice p-3 mb-3"><div class="row"><div class="col-3"><span class="brand-text font-weight-light"><img src="/img/globe.png" alt="Invoice Logo"></span> <br> lightgray;"><div 
 </a> <a href="" class="btn btn-primary float-right" style="margin-right: 5px;"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Generate PDF
 </a></div></div></div>`

Comment: in your case i think you should use built-in print functionnatity in browser

Comment: Like print Invoice and download PDF from there ?

Comment: Getting error on `content`: 
`312 |     head +
  313 |     "<body>"
> 314|     content +
         | ^
  315 |     "</body>" +
  316 |     "</html>"
  317 |   );`

Answer (score 0):

Edit: When I initially answered this question, OP wanted to use jsPDF.

See [How to properly use jsPDF library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858954/how-to-properly-use-jspdf-library)

For vue you'll probably want to generate some sort of unique `id` for each component element so that way you don't grab the first element every time.

```js
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("invoice")[0];
// var ele = document.getElementById("mydiv");
var margins = {
  top: 80,
  bottom: 60,
  left: 40,
  width: 522
};
var cb = function (dispose) {
  pdf.save('Test.pdf');
}
var opt =  { 'width': margins.width };
pdf.fromHTML(ele,margins.left, margins.top, opt, cb, margins)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.4.1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv" class="invoice"><b> Test </b></div>
```

Comment: Getting this error, When i hit download button. `Cannot read property '0' of null`

Comment: wait i'm updating my question.

Answer (score -1):

```
var element = document.getElementById('target-div');
            var opt = {
                margin:0,
                filename: 'myfile.pdf',
                image: {type: 'jpeg',quality: 0.98},
                html2canvas: {scale: 2},
                jsPDF: {
                    unit: 'mm',
                    orientation: 'portrait'
                }
            };

            html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save();
```