# How to save iframe as PDF or Image

Tags: html, pdf, iframe

I am working on a project where we need to save the iframe content as a PDF or an image.
Currently, I getting issue where the PDF is just blank.

Does anyone  has  any solution for this ?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <script  src="jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
        <script src="html2canvas.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.8.1/html2pdf.bundle.min.js" ></script>         
    <script >
        function createPdf(){
        window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF
        var pdf = new jsPDF()
        var element = document.getElementById("capture")
        pdf.save("output.pdf")  
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>        
        <iframe id="capture"  src="https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page" style="  width: 100%; height: 600px" frameborder="0"></iframe>  
        <button onclick="createPdf()">create pdf </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A little dated, but this might assist: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19290964/1772933